# How to tell Mypy that an external package is annotated?

Tags: python, annotations, mypy

I am using an external package that is fully annotated, but does not include the `py.typed` marker.

I have submitted a pull request to add it, but in the meantime I'd like Mypy to know that the package is actually typed, possibly without ignoring the annotations.

By searching the internet I can only find ways to make stubs (which would be overkill and unnecessary in this case) or ignore the package's types (which would basically opt me out of type checking it).

How do I mark an external package as typed?

Comment: If you have write-access to your virtual environment, you can dump a `py.typed` in the root directory of the package. Here's something that will do it for you: https://github.com/orsinium-labs/typeforce

Comment: The code is a big collaborative project which is also checked on CI pipelines, monkeypatching the virtual environment is not an option.

Comment: There's no other way, and there's nothing wrong with monkey-patching in CI IMO. The only alternative (besides already mentioned by you) is to use your own fork until py.typed is added to upstream, but it's certainly overkill.